# Concatenating of martrix of different sizes

Tags: matlab, matrix, concatenation

I want to concatenate 2 4D matrices

```
a1=zeros(28,28,61,11000);
a2=zeros(28,28,61,1100);
```

I have tried to use

```
desiredResult = horzcat(a1, a2);
```

But its not working

Comment: The reason you cannot use `horzcat` is because your two matrices have different dimensions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using `desiredResult=cat(4,a1,a2)`